# eliminar un elemento especifico de un array javascript

Tags: array, poo, objeto, eliminar

tengo un array llamada hotelList donde pido al usuario que ingrese los datos del hotel ;
(esto lo estoy haciendo con la plantilla de class)

```html
[Hotel] 0:  Hotel {#name: 'hotel riviera', #numberOfRooms: 28,
#numberOfFloors: 2, #surfaceOfHotel: 1200} 1:  Hotel {#name: 'Hotel Barcelona', #numberOfRooms: 28, #numberOfFloors: 2, #surfaceOfHotel: 1200} 2:  Hotel {#name: 'Hotel Madrid', #numberOfRooms: 28,
#numberOfFloors: 2, #surfaceOfHotel: 1200} length: 3
```

name; numberOfRooms; numberOfFloors; surfaceOfHotel;

lo he intentado con este codigo pero solo me elimina el ultimo objeto

```js
function eliminateHotel() {
  const userPrompt = prompt(
    "introduce el nombre del hotel que quieras eliminar"
  );
  console.log(hotelList.indexOf(userPrompt === hotelList.name));
  console.log (hotelList.splice(hotelList.indexOf(userPrompt === hotelList.name)))
  console.log(hotelList)
```

como puedo hacer?

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

[Esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array) de SO te muestra algunas formas de lograr esto.

Una de ellas sería emplear [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) que te devuelve una nueva matriz sin mutar la original. Para crear la matriz de retorno, esta función recibe un [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) que evalúa cada elemento de la matriz de origen y solo agrega a la matriz de retorno aquellos que cumplan con una condición.

Dicho esto, puedes obtener solo aquellos elementos que no sean el que quieres eliminar:

```
hoteles = hoteles.filter(hotel => hotel != userPrompt);
```

Creando una matriz solo con los elementos que difieran de la entrada del usuario, es decir, que difieran del hotel que desea eliminar.

```js
let hoteles    = ["Hotel Madrid", "Hotel Bar & Casino", "Hotel Random"];
let userPrompt = prompt("introduce el nombre del hotel que quieras eliminar");
  
// Hoteles sin eliminación
console.log(hoteles);
  
hoteles = hoteles.filter(hotel => hotel != userPrompt);
  
// Hoteles con eliminación
console.log(hoteles);
```